# Reading JBOSS system variable in CAMEL

Tags: jboss, apache-camel

Can someone explain how to read JBOSS system variables (e.g. jboss.bind.address) in CAMEL? We are using CAMEL as part of a web-service which talks to several other backend web-services and we want the piece of code that creates an endpoint to bind to a specific network interface. This information is

Answer (score 0):

Well it should be working with

> System.getProperty("jboss.bind.address");

Comment: The problem was with setting jboss.bind.address. We were not using the -b with the daemon.sh script nor did we set it explicitly in the domain.xml

In the camel-context.xml file, all we had to do was to directly use the system variable. For example -

endpoint="http://${jboss.bind.address}:${svc_port}/${svc_url}